# how to display images pusher real time chat

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pusher

im trying to use images for a real time chat using pusher i cant find anything on how to display images using pusher i store  the images using BLOB but cant display them in the javascript on the client side, the person who types the message the  image comes up just find but on the other person screen its coming back undefined. i didnt post the submit javascript because its working fine just the bind is not good

```
$avatar = 'data:image/png;base64,'. base64_encode( $image );
$pusher = PusherInstance::get_pusher() ;
$pusher->trigger(
    'channel_test',
    'new_comments',
    array('message' => $message ,'user' => $data_user),
    $_POST['socket_id']
);
echo json_encode(array('message' => $message,'user' => $data_user,'avatar'=>$avatar)) ;
```

and then I try to display them using javscript  ,

```
channel.bind('new_comments',function(data){
   $('.chat-widget').append("<div class='row'>\
       <div class='chat_post col-lg-12'>\
        <div class='media'>\
         <a class='pull-left' href='#'>\
              <img class='media-object img-circle' width=30 height=30 src='" + data.avatar +"' alt=''>\
                  </a>\
                  <div class='media-body'>\
                      <h4 class='media-heading chat-name'><a href='profile.php?user=" + data.user + "' class='user_profile'>" + data.user + "</a>\
                          <span class='small pull-right'>12:23 PM</span>\
                      </h4>" + data.message + " </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
                </div>\
            <hr>\
");
```

Comment: How large are your images? You might be hitting the [10kB limit](https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/interact_rest_api#publishing-events). Due to this limit, it is better practice to only send the URL of the image via Pusher, and serve the image itself from your server.

Comment: aye thanks that fixed my problem appreciate it  boss !

Comment: Great; I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, message sizes were over the 10kB limit. Due to this limit, it is better practice to only send the URL of the image via Pusher, and serve the image itself from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Like a modern messenger, store to copy of your image in DB, one should has very small size (Use of images library like **GD** in **php**), reduce size to something like 100X100 pixel and use **Blur** filter to decrease size.
Then Save message AS **BLOB** type in database. then you can send it with socket and you followed pusher rules!

Second copy doesn't save in DB, you must store it in Storage and when message received, user must click on preview image (small size) to download it based on URL.

You can also use of javascript or JQuery to make an auto download mechanism after receive message event fired.